# Problem with tar when using Systemd timer

Tags: command-line, server, backup, cron, systemd

I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 server machine with MS-SQLServer installed.
I'm trying to create a scheduled backup for the databases on weekly basis on Thursday 16:00:00.

The script for creating a backup is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Creating backup directory"
fn="backup-"$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
dir="/data/mssql/$fn"
echo $dir
mkdir $dir
echo "Creating backups"
sqlcmd -H localhost -U SA -P Password -Q "Backup database [DB1] to disk='$dir/DB1.bak'"
sqlcmd -H localhost -U SA -P Password -Q "Backup database [DB2] to disk='$dir/DB2.bak'"

echo "Backups created, creating MD5 checksums"

md5sum $dir/* > $dir/checksum

echo "Checksums created, preparing for upload by compressing folder"

tar -zcvf $fn.tar.gz $dir
```

I use Systemd Timers to schedule the backup process:
The `sqlback.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description= Schedule a weekly backup of MS-SQL Server database

[Timer]
OnCalendar=thu 16:00
Persistent=true
Unit=sqlback.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description= Create weekly backup of MS-SQL Server databases for the DB1 and DB2

[Service]
User=mssql
Group=mssql
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/sql_backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the service starts on its schedule, the backup is created successfully, next is to compress, `tar` fails and gives the following message:

```
آب 15 12:53:22 main bash[9576]: tar: backup-15-08-2018.tar.gz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
آب 15 12:53:22 main bash[9576]: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

However, if I run the script manually using `sudo` and `su`, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a full path into `fn` variable.
Or add

```
 cd $dir
```

Also verify if `mssql` user have privileges to write in backup directory.

Comment: User `mssql` has privileges to write because the .bak files are created successfully

Comment: Upon your suggestion, I used `dir` instead of `fn` and it worked